# How to query for all tabs' urls?

Tags: apex, query, tab, url, apexpage

I am trying to query for all tabs in an org that a user has access to. Also I need their urls so that I can navigate to them.

I was thinking about `[Select Name FROM ApexPage]` but that returns a lot of pages that are not relevant to the tabs in the org. Not sure how else I can do it.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOQL won't help you. You need to get them from the Schema e.g.:

```
// Each app
for (DescribeTabSetResult tsr : Schema.describeTabs()) {
    // Each tab of the app
    for (DescribeTabResult tr : tsr.getTabs() {
        System.debug('getLabel: ' + tr.getLabel());
        System.debug('getUrl: ' + tr.getUrl());
    }            
}
```

Please take a look at this [Describing Tabs Using Schema Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describeTabs.htm) page for more detail.

Hope this helps you.